# How to make default of parent function run if not specified in a wrapper function

Tags: r, function, parameters, wrapper, default

I am writing a wrapper function where I am linking multiple steps of a pipeline. I would like to make it so the user can input multiple options where the value would be input if present, and the default of the paernt function otherwise.

For example

```
orig_func1 <- function(num = 1, x=3, y=2){
   num <- (x + y)/num
   return(num)

orig_func2 <- function(num = 1, z=5, w=23){
   num <- (z - w)/num
   return(num)
```

now I want to create a wrapper to perform each of these a specified amount of times. I want num to change with each iteration as an input for the next function

```
wrapper <- function(
   num = 1,
   steps = list(c(step = NULL, x = NULL, y = NULL),
                c(...),...){
    for (i in 1:length(steps)){
        if (steps[[i]]['step'] == "orig_func1"){
           num <- orig_func1(num = num, x = steps[[i]][['x']], y = steps[[i]][['y']]
           }
        if (steps[[i]]['step'] == "orig_func2"){
           num <- orig_func2(num = num, z = steps[[i]][['z']], y = steps[[i]][['z']]
           }
      }
```

If for example I tried to run this

```
test <- (
   num = 1,
   steps = list(c(step = orig_func1, x = 2, y = 5),
                c(step = orig_func2, z = 4, w = 6), 
                c(step = orig_func1, x = 2) # I want default for y in this case
```

Lets say I try to run this while leaving y blank for the third step because I want default, this would throw an error because steps[[i]][['y']] wont be found. How can I make it so the default of the parent function is used if not present in the step list without respecifiying the defaults in the wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't particularly clear and has many errors so it is hard to see exactly what you're trying to do - for example you aren't returning the numbers you calculate anywhere so the output of your wrapper function will always be NULL.

I think what you're trying to do can be solved by using `base::do.call` to supply the arguments as a list rather than individually extracting them as you've done.

Something like this:

```
wrapper <- function(num = 1,
                    steps = list()){
  for (i in 1:length(steps)){
    
    step_func <- steps[[i]][["step"]] # get function from 'step' element
    
    step_args <- steps[[i]][-1] # remove 'step' element
    
    num <- base::do.call(step_func, step_args) # call function with arguments
   
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was going for. Thank you!